# Inserting datetime into a MS SQL table using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, mssql-jdbc

I'm trying to insert a datetime value into a MS SQL Server table using pyodbc.
If I do it manually, something like:

```
cursor.execute("""insert into currentvalue(value1,currentdatetime)
                                    values(55,'2014-06-27 16:42:48.533')""")
```

I have no problem at all, but when I try to do:

```
currenttime = str(datetime.datetime.now())
cursor.execute("""insert into currentvalue(value1,currentdatetime) 
                                    values(55,"""+ currenttime+")")
```

I got this error:

> SQL server Incorrect syntax near '07' which i think is the number after the date and starting the time.

Also I tried this:

```
currenttime = "'"+str(datetime.datetime.now())+"'"
```

and now this error comes up:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Use [parameters](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted#Parameters).

Answer (score 19):

Remove the datetime to string conversion and instead use parameters:

```
....
cursor.execute("insert into currentvalue (value1,currentdatetime) values(?,?)",
               (value1, datetime.datetime.now()))
....
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use datetime.strftime() to convert datetime object to string in the way you need. str(datetime) is bad idea.

`currenttime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
cursor.execute("""insert into currentvalue(value1,currentdatetime) values(55,"""+ currenttime+")")`

Comment: I think your solution not work and it is just like the questioner first attempt. You need at least a string escape.

Answer (score -1):

You can add single quotes:

```
currenttime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
sql_statement = f"""
insert into currentvalue(value1,currentdatetime)
values(55,'{currenttime}')
""" 
cursor.execute()
```

Comment: Building SQL queries by sticking strings together [is a](https://xkcd.com/327/) [bad habit](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Little_Bobby_Tables)

Comment: @Chris Thank you for the feedback. I didn't know that I was writing vulnerable SQL injection code. Moving forward, I will keep that in mind. See: https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/ for how to write safer code for SQL injection attacks.