# Python date not showing Time in sql server

Tags: python, sql-server, datetime

Using datetime.strptime(11/12/18 02:20 PM, '%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p') I enter the date and time into sql server using a stored procedure and I get no errors, all seems fine.  But the actual value in the database when checked is 2018-11-12 00:00:00.000.  This is the value coming out of strptime 2018-11-12 14:20:00.  Why am I not getting the time value? I have checked both the table design and Stored Procedure to make sure that datetime is being used throughout.

Comment: "No errors" does not necessarily mean "fine." Did you look at the actual value that is getting substituted before you just throw it over the wall at SQL Server?

Comment: Maybe this answer [Inserting datetime into a MS SQL table using pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458124/inserting-datetime-into-a-ms-sql-table-using-pyodbc) might help! Though in this example they were getting errors.

Comment: I will check now for actual value

Comment: This is the value coming out of strptime 2018-11-12 18:20:00

Comment: Is it possible the column in SQL Server is DATE instead of DATETIME? Seems unlikely if you're getting the 00:00:00.000 at the end, but worth checking.

Comment: Checked to be sure and yes datetime

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Figured it out, since I was doing this in 'Ignition' and using a python library, I went into the library file. It was using  'system.db.createSPProcCall' and 'registerInParam' where you must include a value and a type.  Since 'system.db.type' does not have a datetime, they had used DATE, wrong!  I changed it to use TimeStamp.  It worked fine after that. A shout out to @Jeffrey Van Laethem for setting me on the right path.