# Python easiest way to insert a dictionary into a database table?

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I have a dictionary with keys and values like:

```
my_dict = {'a':33, 'b': 'something', 'c': GETDATE(), 'd': 55}
```

Assume column names in the SQL table are also named like the keys of the dict, i.e. "a,b,c,d".

The actual dictionary is 20+ key:value pairs.

#### Code

I have used [pyodbc.connect](https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/) to create a `cursor` which I could use to execute an SQL INSERT statement:

```
for k in my_dict.keys():
    cursor.execute(
    '''
        INSERT INTO TABLEabc (%s)
        VALUES (%s)
    '''
    % (k, my_dict[k])
    )
```

This seems inefficient though because it's a new SQL operation each time.

1. What is the easiest way to insert the values using a loop?
2. How could I write it so that it just makes one insert with all the values?

Comment: So your table like `TABLEabc` has 20+ columns (like the key-value pairs in your dict)? And you would expect 1 single INSERT statement for this single dict to create 1 table-row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using pyodbc then this might work:

```py
columns = {row.column_name for row in cursor.columns(table='TABLEabc')}

safe_dict = {key: val for key, val in my_dict.items() if key in columns}

# generate a parameterised query for the keys in our dict
query = "INSERT INTO TABLEabc ({columns}) VALUES ({value_placeholders})".format(
    columns=", ".join(safe_dict.keys()),
    value_placeholders=", ".join(["?"] * len(safe_dict)),
)

cursor.execute(query, list(safe_dict.values()))
```

It is intended to be safe from SQL injection because:

- we filter for only keys which are actual column names in the db
- we use pyodbc cursor execute params, so the values will be escaped properly

Where it possibly won't work:

- if any of the column names need to be quoted and escaped, this won't happen automatically so it will fail

Quoting/escaping is db-specific so we would have to check the rules for our actual db and apply that to the dict keys that we format into the query. (or find some way to get pyodbc to do that for us, not sure if possible)

If you trust your `my_dict` not to contain malicious code then you can simplify to just:

```py
query = "INSERT INTO TABLEabc ({columns}) VALUES ({value_placeholders})".format(
    columns=", ".join(my_dict.keys()),
    value_placeholders=", ".join(["?"] * len(my_dict)),
)

cursor.execute(query, list(my_dict.values()))
```

Comment: ```columns``` returns an empty set. Can I just use ```my_dict.keys()``` instead for columns? What is ```columns``` supposed to return?

Comment: @Mitch yes you certainly can, as long as you trust the keys, e.g. if it is a dict you have hard-coded yourself and doesn't come from user input

Comment: I do trust the keys yes they are hard-coded. But I get an error ```TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not callable```. What type is ```columns``` supposed to be?

Comment: here `columns=", ".join(safe_dict.keys())` you should be able to just do `columns=", ".join(my_dict.keys())` ... just replace `safe_dict` with `my_dict` everywhere basically

Comment: and get rid of the first two lines of my answer, you don't need to construct `safe_dict`.  `columns` is a set in my answer

Comment: updated the answer with what I mean

Comment: I get an error when trying to pass 'GETDATE()' ```DataError: ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (241) (SQLExecDirectW)')``` do you know how to convert it to be passed?

Comment: @Mitch probably better as a separate question. Is `GETDATE` your own function? What does it return? This answer suggests just give pyodbc a python datetime object https://stackoverflow.com/a/24458420/202168

Answer (score 1):

Using SQLAlchemy, this dictionary matches my table construct in SQL Server

```
mydict = {
  "Name": "Laura", "Form": "4B","Year": "7", "DOB" : "", "Col_5" : "",
  "Col_6" : "","Col_7" : "","Col_8" : ""  
}

print(mydict)
```

and I use this to pass the keys and values to a string (with some manipulation) into my table, which is called pypupil)
I also wanted to write data for all records, whether present in the Dictionary or not.

```
fields = (str(list(mydict.keys()))[1:-1])
values = (str(list(mydict.values()))[1:-1])

columns = ', '.join("`" + str(x).replace('/', '_') + "`" for x in mydict.keys())
values = ', '.join("'" + str(x).replace('/', '_') + "'" for x in mydict.values())
sql = "INSERT INTO %s ( %s ) VALUES ( %s );" % ('pypupil', columns, values)

sql = sql.replace ( "`","") 
print(sql)

with engine.connect() as con:
    rs = con.execute(sql)
```

A bit more info and lots of helpers for this approach here.
https://discuss.dizzycoding.com/using-a-python-dict-for-a-sql-insert-statement/

Comment: Look for Answer 5 /6 in the above link

Comment: NOTE: With SQLAlchemy 1.4+, exiting a `with engine.begin() as conn:` block will automatically *commit* if no errors have occurred. Exiting a `with engine.connect() as conn:` block will automatically *rollback* if no errors have occurred.

Comment: That's useful to know, thanks @GordThompson.

Comment: @JonTout do you know how to add id auto-increment to it? I get error ArgumentError: Column type NUMERIC(18, 0) on column 'tableABC.p_ID' is not compatible with autoincrement=True

Answer (score 1):

Supplemental to [JonTout's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72536497/2144390), if you use SQLAlchemy then your dict is ready-made to be consumed by a SQLAlchemy Core `Table` object:

```py
import datetime

import sqlalchemy as sa

connection_url = sa.engine.URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", … )
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)

table_abc = sa.Table("TABLEabc", sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

my_dict = {'a':33, 'b': 'something', 'c': datetime.date.today(), 'd': 55}

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(table_abc.insert(), my_dict)
```

Comment: do you know how to add id auto-increment to it? I get error ```ArgumentError: Column type NUMERIC(18, 0) on column 'tableABC.p_ID' is not compatible with autoincrement=True```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the connection. Are you trying to modify the Table object after it has been reflected? You may need to ask a new question.

Comment: No I'm trying to complete the insert into a table that has an auto-increment PK, but I get that error. Do you need to specify its auto-increment in the sql insert?

Comment: In my example below the columns specified are Name, Form, Year etc -you won't insert data into an auto increment. The print(sql) command will generate the sql string that you can paste into SSMS.

Comment: @Mitch - You may have found a bug. https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/8111

Comment: @GordThompson did you get the same Error?

Comment: @Mitch - Yes, it's in the GitHub issue.

Comment: Is a NUMERIC ID column unusual? Are they usually INT that's why it wasn't seen before?

Comment: @Mitch - Yes, indeed.